# Creating Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition ISO

Tags: windows-installer, visual-studio-2017

i want to create offline installer (an ISO file) of visual studio 2017 community edition, but i dont want to download FULL features of it, i only want to install :

```
1. Universal Windows Platform Development
2. Desktop development with C++
3. .NET desktop development
4. Mobile development with .NET (XAMARIN)
```

i downloaded offline web installer from : [ms.web](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/install-vs-inconsistent-quality-network) but i don't know what to add on command prompt so i can download 4 components that i said before. Please tell me the command to add on command prompt so i can get those component only.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply write the below command in CMD after opening it in the same folder where you downloaded the web installer (vs_Community.exe)

`vs_community.exe --layout d:\vs2017offline --lang en-US`

But take my word, there's no need to do that at all, I tried it today, and the ISO file reached 21.5GB so I stopped it.

Also, you can refer to Microsoft official blog for more details:
https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToMakeAnOfflineInstallerForVS2017.aspx